# Java object serialized without implementing serializable interface

Tags: java, serialization, exception

I have the following code.

Animal.java

```
   public class Animal{
        String name;
        int age;

        public Animal(){
            name="default name";
            age=0;
        }

    }
```

Cat.java

```
  public class Cat extends Animal{
        int legs;
        public Cat(){
            super();
            this.legs=10;
        }
    }
```

Test.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try{
            Cat c1 = new Cat();
            FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("myobjects.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
            objectStream.writeObject(c1);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }
}
```

This code works without any issue. There is no exception thrown. I was expecting an exception because the cat class has not implemented serializable interface.

Why did my code work?

Comment: I get an exception. Recompile and rerun your code.

Comment: I am not getting any. using open-jdk7

Comment: I'm getting java.io.NotSerializableException. Check well

Comment: e.printStackTrace() printis it to the err stream which may not be visible to you. That is why you believed the code worked as it silently finished.

Comment: how do i make the exception to print to my stdout?

Comment: System.out.println(e)

Comment: When you ask a question, please post only the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem. In this case, you could have omitted the `Animal` class. The essence of your question would still remain, but readers have much less code to sift through.

Comment: Next time, i will keep that in mind. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program DOES throw an exception, you just aren't looking in the right place.

The method `e.printStackTrace()` prints to the `System.err` (STDERR) stream, *NOT* to the standard console output (STDOUT). It is highly likely that you are not looking at the right stream. Most IDE's will show `System.err` but I can't speak for yours.

A fix would be calling `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`. This will print the exception message to STDOUT. If you want to print the stack trace, you should call `e.printStackTrace(System.out)`.

It is better practice to find a way to view the `System.err` (STDERR) stream, as the typical `System.out` is used for normal program output, not errors. You can call `System.err.println(e.getMessage())` to get the exception message, and `e.printStackTrace(System.err)` to get the stack trace.

Comment: I'd rather use `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` or `System.err.println(e.getMessage());`. As for the stack trace, `e.printStackTrace(System.out);` will print it to STDOUT, and `e.printStackTrace(System.err);` will print it to STDERR

Comment: You are correct. Was a bit distracted when writing my answer! I will edit later.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include my observations. Hope it's helpful

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you shouldn't be catching "Exception". Bad practice.

Secondly, if you want to "view" the exception, let the main() method throw the NotSerializableException (using throws).

Comment: This answer is not correct... (The first sentence is, but that doesn't answer the question)